# How can I install pythonds module?

Tags: python, data-structures, stack, python-module

when I run a programme containing:-

from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack

it says:-
ImportError: No module named pythonds.basic.stack

Please help me out.

Answer (score 6):

`pip install pythonds`.

And then `from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack`. Note that it's `Stack`, not `stack`.

Comment: If using Python 3.x you can use `pip3 install pythonds`. Type this into Terminal (or cmd if you're on Windows, I believe) and press `Enter`

Comment: Thank you for your response.!Sorry, it was typing mistake when asking the question, but I haven't got the solution yet. I am using Python 2.7 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the Python PATH variable configured, then type this into your command prompt:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip install LIBRARY NAME
```

This path is only and example. change it wherever you have Python in your pc.

Comment: It gives no such file or directory

Comment: You need to use the file path where your version of python is saved. If you are using python version 2.7 then replace the 34 with 27, and same with any other version of python. I just suggested the default directory which is the C drive for windows computers.